# Earliest documented use of caste system?

Tags: caste-system

What is the earliest use of modern-day caste system in India? Where is this documented so I can reference it?

CLARIFICATIONS: These clarifications respond to questions and apparent confusions about what is a simple question. If there is no answer please say so. If down voting, please indicate your reasons. Since caste system is one of the great by-products of Hinduism, it is a valid topic of inquiry.

Modern-day, I meant as we currently understand. I wanted to exclude any ancient categories, such gods or demi-gods or other non-human categories. If I knew anymore about the evolution of castes, I probably won't be asking this question.

By documented, I meant justification for maintaining those categories into modern age, which includes recent colonial periods.

By reference, I meant any other resources besides bibliographic. I kept this deliberately open knowing Hinduism's strong oral tradition. It need not be restricted to scriptures or religious canons.

Comment: So what is modern day caste-system and from where do you expect the documentation for that? In ancient hindu texts? Off topic.

Comment: Your question is a little difficult to answer as you refer to 'modern' caste system, not just caste system. The four varnashramas, castes, are mentioned throughout the Vedas, the Gita, and other scriptures. How those varnashramas have come to be actually practiced now is much different than ancient times.

Comment: So caste system is in Vedas, the Gita, and other scriptures, and the question I ask is when did it start and it becomes off-topic? Off-topic on a Hinduism Stackoverflow? Give me a break. I know this topic causes a lot of consternation among modern privileged Indians, but do you have to curtail discussion on a western website. I beg people responsible for flagging this as off-topic to allow posters like pa1 (see below) to add to our understanding however inconvenient it might be. Instead why not add your wisdom to pa1's contribution?

Comment: If you had simply asked, "What is the origin of the caste system?" without all this mention of "modern-day", then I think your question wouldn't have been closed.  It's certainly possible to give an answer on what the origin of the caste system is based on Hindu scripture.  Like there are scriptures that talk about people who do different actions being born into different castes in their next birth, discussion of the origins of the castes in the Purusha Sukta of the Rig Veda, etc.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, I am not asking for speculative origins, but best case for documentation? In your case for example, what is "being born into different castes"? You use it as if caste were a race or a biological category. Please keep the question open so people who understand the question may answer.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by best case for documentation.  Are you asking for the earliest mention of the caste system?  That would be in the Vedas.  In any case, I think if you just asked "What is the earliest mention of the caste system" rather than all this talk of the modern day, your question wouldn't be closed.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan why don't you give an answer if you know? Re-cast the question if you have to. And then I'll decide if it is appropriate. Your attitude about fixing my question does not instill confidence in your ability to answer or moderate.

Comment: @EmacsUser Well, my proposed edit would be to change the title to "What is the earliest mention of the caste system?" and remove everything that's currently in the body of the question.

Comment: Then put that in your answer and reasons why my question as posed is inappropriate.

Comment: @EmacsUser While I agree your question is not off-topic (the reason that's been cited to close it), but your language _"Modern-day, I meant as we currently understand,"_ will lead to [opinion-based](http://goo.gl/iosGyZ) answers/discussion which is highly discouraged here. What _I_ currently understand and what _you_ currently understand will lead to lot of debate and there cannot be single correct answer. I created a chat room for you [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35592/hindu-caste-systems) on this topic. If you are lucky, some interested users may participate ;)

Comment: @sv, thanks much. How can asking for documented source create opinion? If there are multiple sources, so be it. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @EmacsUser Like I said, if you edit your question along the lines I suggested, removing references to the modern day, then it may be reopened, and then I'd be happy to try to answer it.

Comment: @EmacsUser Then you should make your question very specific. Modify the first line to: _What is the earliest use of caste system in India?_ (Remove 'modern-day' as has been already suggested), the less 'noise' the better in your question. The word _justification_ will also lead to lot of debate especially when it comes to caste-system (which is why I guess your question was down-voted), so it's more suited to a chat room or comments section of an answer.

Comment: @EmacsUser many questions already clarify Varna, Jati, or as Westerners call "Caste" Usually I find Varna/Jati of three types. One by birth, qualities, and actions/duties. While I cannot provide sources the first use of Varna or Jati in India was likely during the Vedic period. Social hierarchies are usually created in times of need to ensure society works more efficiently. This is more of a history question, but I suggest you look at if there was any big calamity that led to its formation. As per the Rig Veda the Purusha Suktam is the first time it's mentioned.

Comment: @EmacsUser Although some see it as a later interpolation due to the etymology of the verse.

Comment: @EmacsUser However, keep in mind that as Hindus religiously we see Varna as eternal how it's distinguished is up for debate in regards to scriptures.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about Indian caste-system. 
There are several theories regarding the origins of the Indian caste system. One posits that the Indian and Aryan classes ("pistras") show similarity wherein the priests are Brahmins, the warriors are Kshatriya, the merchants are Vaishya, and the artisans are Shudras.Another theory is that of Georges Dumézil, who formulated thetrifunctional hypothesis of social class. According to the Dumézil theory, ancient societies had three main classes, each with distinct functions: the first judicial and priestly, the second connected with the military and war, and the third class focused on production, agriculture, craft and commerce. Dumézil proposed that Rex-Flamen of the Roman Empire is etymologically similar to Raj-Brahman of ancient India and that they made offerings to deus and deva respectively, each with statutes of conduct, dress and behaviour that were similar.

Caste used to be considered as an ancient fact of Hindu life, but various contemporary scholars have argued that the caste system as it exists today is the result of the British colonial regime, which made caste organisation a central mechanism of administration.According to scholars such as the anthropologist Nicholas Dirks, before colonialism caste affiliation was quite loose and fluid, but the British regime enforced caste affiliation rigorously, and constructed a much more strict hierarchy than existed previously, with some castes being criminalised and others being given preferential treatment.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.

Comment: Well, that certainly is the case now in India, but Varna did impact the lives of many in ancient India. Both positively and negatively the situation was different back then. That being said in my pov the Bhagavad Gita summarizes it best and Yudhishthir support this teaching.